# Video capture in VPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture

What is the best way to capture video in a WPF application? I am looking for a way to detect the video devices, and then capture video from the selected one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no WPF support for this. You need to use the traditional, expected windows APIs for video capture, such as DXVA.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using ActiveX controls in WPF app, you can use VideoCapX from http://www.fathsoft.com/videocapx.html